# How angularjs method `$http.post` works?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just using this code and I wanted to alert its response

```
$http.post('test.php',{id:index});
```

so I used this code

```
alert(($http.post('test.php',{id:index}).data));
```

I dont understand how angularjs method `$http.post` is differ from below code. and how data comes in above code ?

```
$http({
    url: "test.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {id:index}
}).success(function(data) {
   alert(data);
}).error(function(error) {
});
```

test.php is

```
<?php
    echo "TestName";
?>
```

Comment: For your information: The `success` and `error` methods are deprecated: "The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error." So instead of using `$http().success().error();` use `$http().then(function resolved () {}, function rejected () {});` See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

1. Assumes that the `post` function returns an object with a `data` property on it.
2. Assumes that the `post` function *blocks* while doing the POST (e.g., is synchronous).

Neither of those assumptions is correct. `post` *starts* the POST but returns immediately, before the POST completes. The value it returns is a *promise*, which is a formalized means of handling callbacks for asynchronous operations. Promises have `then`, `error`, and similar functions on them.

In your second example, the code runs, and then **later** when the POST is complete, if it's successful the `success` callback is called, passing in the data.

This is covered in [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and (for promises) [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: Thanks, Now I noticed